# Ho to verify if event receiver is custom or default in share point 2013

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, event-receivers

I have requirement to get all the list of event receiver names(Not Default) in a share point 2013 site which are custom.

Kindly guide me on identifying the custom receivers only.

Thanks in advance!
Kailash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Iterate the event receivers using `Get-PnPEventReceiver` and look at the `ReceiverAssembly` property. The ones that start with "Microsoft" are OOB. The ones that are blank, like in the below screen shot, are remote event receivers. Your custom server-side event receivers will have the name of the assembly they were created under.

`Get-PnPEventReceiver -List $listName | ft ReceiverName,ReceiverAssembly`

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/get-pnpeventreceiver

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.
I Have retrieved the details using power shell. But for some of the event receivers the assembly shows as 'Nintex.Workflow, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=913f6bae0ca5ae12'.

So, can Nintex  have event receiver in sharepoint?

Comment: Yep, that's a third party application, not OOB.